# Passing arguments using drupal_get_form()

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

Here is my custom module using hook,

Assume if I want to pass argument to custom1_default_form function call, how should i pass the argument?

```
<?php

function custom1_block($op,$delta=0){
    if($op=='list'){
        $block = array();
        $block[0]['info']=t('hello world');
        return $block;
    }else if($op=='view'){
        $block_content = '<p>THIS IS MY FIRST BLOCK</p>';
        $block['subject'] = 'HELLO WORLD';
        $block['content'] =drupal_get_form('custom1_default_form');
        return $block;      
    }  
}

function custom1_default_form () {
  $form = array();
    $form['nusoap_urls']['txt_name']  =
    array('#type' => 'textfield',
          '#title' => t('Please enter your name'),
          '#default_value' => variable_get('webservice_user_url',''),
          '#maxlength' => '40',
          '#size' => '20',
         // '#description' => t('<br />Root directory used to present the filebrowser user interface.')

          );
     $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Save Details'),
      );          
        return $form;    
  }

  function custom1_default_form_validate (&$form, &$form_state) {

    if(($form_state['values']['txt_name']) == '') {
        form_set_error('user_webservice', t('Enter a name'));
    }
  }

  function custom1_default_form_submit ($form_id, $form_values) {
 // drupal_set_message( print_r($_POST));

 //  $message = 'You have submitted the ' . $form_id . ' form which contains the following data:<pre>' . print_r($form_state['values'],true) . '</pre>';

  //drupal_set_message(t($message));
  //drupal_set_message(t($form_values['values']['txt_name']));
 // print_r($form_values['values']);
    $GET_TXT_FIELD_VALUE = $form_values['values']['txt_name'];
    $INSERT_QUERY = "INSERT INTO sample (test_name) VALUES ('$GET_TXT_FIELD_VALUE')";
    if (db_result(db_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {sample} WHERE test_name = '%s';", $GET_TXT_FIELD_VALUE))) {
        // User doesn't exist
        drupal_set_message(t('ALREADY EXIST.....'));
     }else{
        db_query($INSERT_QUERY)or die('Execution Failed');
        if(db_affected_rows()==1){
            drupal_set_message(t('VALUE INSERTED SUCCESSFULLY'));
        }else{
            drupal_set_message(t('VALUE INSERTED FAILED'));
        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to pass an argument via the URL, use [`arg()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/arg):

```
function custom1_default_form() {
  // Assuming the URL is http://example.com/admin/content/types:
  $arg1 = arg(1); // $arg1 = 'content'
  $arg2 = arg(2); // $arg2 = 'types'
  // ...
}
```

If you just want to pass an argument to the form via the `drupal_get_form()` call, just add the arguments as additional parameters to [`drupal_get_form()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/drupal_get_form/6):

```
$block['content'] = drupal_get_form('custom1_default_form', $arg1, $arg2);

// ...

function custom1_default_form($form_state, $arg1, $arg2) {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I have found that in Drupal 6.20 you should add a dummy argument to the callback function definition:

$block['content'] = drupal_get_form('custom1_default_form', $arg1, $arg2);

// ...

function custom1_default_form($dummy, $arg1, $arg2) { // look at what gets stored in $dummy
  // ...
}

Answer (score 1):

avoid the using of arg() functions when possible:

> Avoid use of this function where possible, as resulting code is hard
>   to read. In menu callback functions, attempt to use named arguments.
>   See the explanation in menu.inc for how to construct callbacks that
>   take arguments. When attempting to use this function to load an
>   element from the current path, e.g. loading the node on a node page,
>   use menu_get_object() instead.