# Pass customized multiple arguments by form

Tags: php

I have a table with books informations and the user must have the option to
sort the table as he wish.

There are three options:

```
Author, Title, Edition
```

all they can be ASCENDING or DESCENDING.

But there is no order in that selection. The user can select: **Title ASC and Edition DESC** or **Author DESC and Edition ASC and Title DESC** or even just **Edition ASC**.

The question is. Which way is better to create this in PHP? By Forms? Arrays? How can i suppose to manage this information to be like this?

```
{"Author" => "Desc", "Title" => "Asc"}
```

I've already got the sorting script, i just need to understand how can i manage customized information like this way. I think arrays would be better but how can i pass through Forms?

**I've tried to figure out but all solutions i though are ugly and have a poor code.**

Here's a picture of the service just for those who did not understand:

[image]

Here's basically the code of everything until now:

```
<?php
    $file = file_get_contents('books.json');
    $json = json_decode($file, true);
    $json = array_map(function($a) { return $a['book'][0]; }, $json['books']);
    foreach ($json as $key => $row):
        $title[$key] = $row['Title'];
        $author[$key] = $row['Author'];
        $edition[$key] = $row['Edition'];
    endforeach;
    array_multisort($title, SORT_ASC, $author, SORT_ASC, $json); // This is the default
    ?>
    <form method="post">
        <table align="center">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Sort By
                </td>
                <td>
                    Direction
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <select class="select" id="firstRule" name="firstRule">
                        <option value="">Select</option>
                        <option value="Author">Author</option>
                        <option value="Title">Title</option>
                        <option value="Edition">Edition</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select id="firstRuleOrder" name="firstRuleOrder">
                        <option value="">Select</option>
                        <option value="up">Ascendent</option>
                        <option value="down">Descendent</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit">   
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: i think that could help you with your forms  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887321/passing-arguments-using-drupal-get-form

Comment: If you show some code, even ugly code, it might help more than the picture. Do you want multiple "sort by" and "direction" dropdowns?

Comment: @fab, i've edited with the base of all code until now

Comment: You should consider handling sorting on the client side, unless, for some reason, you need to support browsers with Javascript disabled.

Comment: @crush, that script in special, must be in server side. It's a exercise.

Comment: if you want to have multi sort, and pagination, the best solution is to send ajax request at each time the sort is changing, and update the content of the table with the ajax response (which should be tabe data on JSON array). In all case, you can take a look at http://www.datatables.net/ which is jQuery plugin for table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of "firstRule" and "firstRuleOrder" the dropdowns should be named "rule[0]" and "ruleOrder[0]". Then duplicate them with increasing array indexes (you can do that with JavaScript or just show as many as there are columns).

To construct your call to `array_multisort`, you will have to iterate over `$_POST['rule']` and `$_POST['ruleOrder']` and create an array of arguments. The actual function call then happens with `call_user_func_array` (that's necessary because you don't know the number of arguments in advance)